# Main functions, pythonic?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I am just getting into Python coding and I'm wondering which is considered more pythonic?
Example A: An obvious main method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt

import random

def dice_roll(num=1):
    for _ in range(num):
        print("Rolled a", random.randrange(1,7,1))

def main()
    random.seed()
    try:
        num = int(input("How many dice? "))
        dice_roll(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Non-numeric Input")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

or Example B: No main method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt

import random

def dice_roll(num=1):
    for _ in range(num):
        print("Rolled a", random.randrange(1,7,1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()
    try:
        num = int(input("How many dice? "))
        dice_roll(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Non-numeric Input")
```

Any help/pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A is better because it allows you to import your module *and* execute the stuff in `main` without having to funk about with things unnecessarily.  In fact, that might be a good reason to name it something better than `main` if it really represents an actual function of your module.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when it comes to being *Pythonic*, I'd say both are equally *Pythonic*, because that refers to specific programming conventions, and doesn't (and shouldn't) govern the way you code.

*However*, people usually, use the first form, as it's easier to `import` and invoke the script from another one, then.

Answer (score 1):

I would say example A is more Pythonic but they are both acceptable. Mainly because you can import main, but usually you would not need to do so.